# Double integral using integration by parts

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to simplify the following integral, $I$:

\begin{equation}
I = \int_{c}^{d}\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} f(x,y)g(x,y) dx dy
\end{equation}

In terms of the constant $\Psi$, given I know that:
\begin{equation}
\int_{c}^{d}\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} g(x,y) dx dy = \Psi
\end{equation}

To do this I intend to use the integration by parts formula:
\begin{equation}
\int_A^B u'(x)v(x) dx = u(x)v(x)\big]_A^B - \int_A^B u(x)v'(x)dx
\end{equation}

---

My (unsuccessful/incorrect) attempt so far:

Using integration by parts for the inner integral and let $u' = f$ and let $v=g$
\begin{equation}
I = \int_{c}^{d}\Bigg(   g(x,y)\int f(x,y)dx \Big]_{a(y)}^{b(y)} - \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} \Big( \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \int f(x,y) dx \Big)dx   \Bigg) dy
\end{equation}

But I'm unsure about the limits of the integral. Perhaps I can do integration by parts of each of the individual terms inside the integral once more, and maybe I can find $I$ in terms of $\Psi$.

Comment: Are you seeking a general formula or is this for a particular problem? If the latter, you may be better off showing us the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is related to a much larger particular problem. However, the only relevant context that I could add is that I'm integrating over the unit circle. So perhaps polar coordinates could be a wiser choice.

Comment: Actually here's a bit more context. The values of $f(x,y)$ are different for each experiment. However, the values of $g(x,y,\psi)$ are the exact same for each experiment. Where $\psi$ is a variable independent of $x$ and $y$. To make my numerical calculations faster I want to find $I(\psi) = \int \int f(x,y) g(x,y,\psi) dxdy$ by exploiting the fact that I know $\int \int g(x,y,\psi) dxdy = $ some function of $\psi$.